# How to set AbandonedConfig in JedisPool - JedisExhaustedPoolException error

Tags: redis, connection-pooling, jedis, apache-commons-pool

I am facing an issue similar to the one [jedis-1929](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/1929). We are using JedisPool with `maxTotal=400` and have ensured that after using jedis from `pool.getResource()` we are returning the connection back to the pool in `finally` block using `jedis.close()` method. Version of jedis is `3.0.0`. The issue appears after continuously running the program for several days. We are getting/setting key-value pair in Redis around 0.1m times per minute. The key and values are both quite small, values approx 120 bytes. Use-case is mostly read heavy.

Wanted to set AbandonConfig to ensure leaked connections if any get closed after a default timeout, but don't see a way to set AbandonConfig related settings for JedisPool. Following is the exception we get, when numActives become equal to maxTotal

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisExhaustedPoolException: Could not get a resource since the pool is exhausted
        at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:234)
        at com.til.ibeat.connection.RedisConnection.getconnection(RedisConnection.java:52)
        at com.til.ibeat.service.impl.RedisCacheServiceImpl.pushToRedisSet(RedisCacheServiceImpl.java:188)
        at com.til.ibeat.service.impl.MessageEnrichService.getVisitorType(MessageEnrichService.java:541)
        at com.til.ibeat.service.impl.MessageEnrichService.populateVisitorType(MessageEnrichService.java:439)
        at com.til.ibeat.service.impl.IbeatEventLogService.process(IbeatEventLogService.java:111)
        at com.til.ibeat.service.impl.IbeatEventLogService$2.call(IbeatEventLogService.java:70)
        at com.til.ibeat.service.impl.IbeatEventLogService$2.call(IbeatEventLogService.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Pool exhausted
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:452)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
        at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:50)
        ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Following is our configuration:

```
    <bean id="redisPool2" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig" ref="poolConfig2"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.lang.String" value="${jedis2.host}" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" type="int" value="${jedis2.port:6379}"/>
        <constructor-arg index="3" type="int" value="${jedis2.timeout.millis:200}"/>
        <constructor-arg index="4" type="java.lang.String" value="${jedis2.password}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="poolConfig2" class="org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig">
        <property name="maxTotal" value="${jedis2.max.total:-1}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${jedis2.max.idle:50}" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="${jedis2.min.idle:3}" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="${jedis2.test.on.borrow:true}" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="${jedis2.test.on.return:false}" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="${jedis2.test.while.idle:false}" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="${jedis2.min.evictable.idle.time.millis:2000}" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="${jedis2.time.between.eviction.runs:30000}" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="${jedis2.tests.per.eviction.run:10}" />
        <property name="blockWhenExhausted" value="${jedis2.block.when.exhausted:false}" />
        <property name="jmxEnabled" value="${jedis2.jmx.enabled:true}"/>
        <property name="jmxNamePrefix" value="${jedis2.host}"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @ArbazSheikh - no. Will have to create own wrappers if we want to achieve this.

Comment: I am also returning the connection back to the pool in finally block using jedis.close() method. Did you find the exact reason for this kind of error

Comment: This was already reported here [#2050](https://github.com/redis/jedis/issues/2050) and also a PR was raised [#2054](https://github.com/redis/jedis/pull/2054) .. but did not make it to merge...